# NetBeans debugging issue

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans, xdebug, netbeans-7

When I click the debug button, I get a browser open up pointing to the following url:

```
http://localhost/www/somepage.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug
```

For some reason it keeps inserting the `www` into the url

If I manually remove the `www` from the browser address bar, the debugging continues as it should.

Anyone know how to get it to stop adding that `www` to the url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the **"Project URL"** and **"Index file"** values in Project properties and "Run configuration" tab.

Netbeans gives you a reminder of the final URL, just under the **"Arguments"** input field. You should see an URL like this :

`http://localhost/www/index.php`

Hope this helps !

Comment: I'll check this out and reply tonight hopefully.